# Django-filter field name is a python builtin keyword

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I'm trying to rebuild a legacy API with DRF and [**django-filter**](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/master/). One of the field names is `from`, but

`from = DateTimeFilter(field_name="created_dt", lookup_expr="gte")`

is not valid Python. Can I name the variable

`from_ = DateTimeFilter(...)`

but still expose the API parameter as `?from=` to users?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the **`__init__()`** method of **`FilterSet`** class

```
from django_filters import rest_framework as drf_filters


class FooFilterSet(drf_filters.FilterSet):
    foo = drf_filters.CharFilter()  # some random field

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.filters["from"] = drf_filters.DateTimeFilter(field_name="created_dt", lookup_expr="gte")

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ('foo', 'from')
```

Answer (score 0):

[JPG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57602690/14421537) solution doesn't work for me in django-filter 2.4.0, throws an error
`TypeError: 'Meta.fields' must not contain non-model field names: from`.

I solved it by overriding the metaclass method:

```
import django_filters
from django.db.models import QuerySet
from django_filters.filterset import FilterSetMetaclass

class FilterSetMetaclassWithFrom(FilterSetMetaclass):
    """Replaces 'from_' FilterField to 'from'"""

    @classmethod
    def get_declared_filters(cls, bases, attrs):
        filters = super().get_declared_filters(bases, attrs)
        if 'from_' in filters:
            filters['from'] = filters['from_']
            del filters['from_']
        return filters
        
        
class FromFilterSet(django_filters.FilterSet, metaclass=FilterSetMetaclassWithFrom):
    to = django_filters.CharFilter(method='filter_to')
    from_ = django_filters.CharFilter(method='filter_from')

    class Meta:
        model = MySuperModel
        fields = []
        
    def filter_to(self, queryset: QuerySet[UserModel], name: str, value: str):
        # some logic
        return queryset

    def filter_from(self, queryset: QuerySet[UserModel], name: str, value: str):
        # Note that the name == 'from_', not 'from'!
        # some logic
        return queryset
```